# What is $\int \frac{e^x}{(e^x - 3)(e^{2x}+1)}dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I get a final answer of $\frac{3\ln \left | e^x -3 \right |}{10} - \frac{3\ln \left | e^{2x} +1 \right |}{20} +\frac{\ln \left | e^{2x} + 1 \right |}{20} + C$ but it seems off, any help would be appreciated!

I used rationalizing substitution then partial fractions.

My partial fractions go as follows:
$\frac{u}{(u-3)(u^2 +1)}= \frac{3}{10(u-3)} + \frac{-3u+1}{10(u^2 +1)}$

Comment: Why does it seems off? (I'm not saying it's true...)

Comment: and what specific substitution did you make?

Comment: @user24142 e^x = u

Comment: @anderstood I popped it into symbolab and although it used a weird technique and had it in a different form, they looked different

Comment: So the denominator has a (u-3) and a (u^2 +1), so you should have a term with each of those as denominator. What is the integral of (Au + B)/(u^2+1)?

Comment: theres one mistake

Comment: i now have a new answer @user24142

Comment: @Tyler You most likely messed up on setting up partial fractions.

Comment: @MathNoob I updated my question with my partial fractions

Comment: @MathNoob it equals for me

Comment: @MathNoob are they somehow equivalent?

Comment: @Tyler My apologies, I messed up on my partial fractions. So your first answer was  correct , the one with the arctangent.

Comment: @MathNoob i found the mistake. When calculating the partial fractions there should be a 1 instead of a u in the numerator, therefore you were originally right.

Comment: @Tyler no, you were correct. I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx \,e^x}{(e^x-3)(e^{x^2}+1)}
&= \int\frac{du}{(u-3)(u^2+1)}\tag{$u=e^x$} \\
&= \int du \, \frac{-3u+1}{10(u^2+1)}+\frac{3}{10(u-3)} \\
&= \int du \, \frac{-3u}{10(u^2+1)}+\int du \,\frac{1}{10(u^2+1)}+\int du \,\frac{3}{10(u-3)} \\
&= -\frac {3}{20}\log|u^2+1|+\frac{\tan^{-1} u}{10}+ \frac{3\log |u-3|}{10}+C \\
&= -\frac {3}{20}\log|e^{2x}+1|+\frac{\tan^{-1} e^x}{10}+ \frac{3\log |e^x-3|}{10}+C
\end{align}

Comment: hmm... i get the 2 terms with 3/10 instead of 1